# sed behaves strange on android tablet

Tags: sed, android

Hi I'm new to using `sed`

When I type:

```
echo day | sed /s/day/night/
```

the output is:

```
nightday
```

In other words, it just appends the entire line after the substitution.  I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab A, running Android 6.01.  When I type `which sed` I get `/system/bin/sed` and when I type `sed --version` I get `This is not GNU sed version 9.0`.

I saw a couple posts about this already online.  And people were saying this might be a buggy version of sed.  Are there any other ways to do search and replace in shell scripts (or just an automated fashion) on an android tablet?

I installed something called "busybox" which provides something called `ed`, but again, I was having problems doing the substitution command.  It would work sometimes, but other times it would say "no substitutions found for ___ (short, basic regex statement I got from a book which is supposed to be compatible with all versions of regex - okay, that sounds vague here's the regex statement:  `^.*\bthe\b.*$`  (The file contains lots of "the" words.)

I guess my options are:  A) try to install linux onto this tablet, B) don't use the tablet at all, C) keep looking for software that will do automated search and replaces on the tablet or try to identify what the bug is in sed and if there's a special code word it needs to work right, D) ?

EDIT:  Added info per request:
When I typed

```
echo day | od -c
```

I got

```
37777776620   d   a   y   \n
37777776620
```

When I typed

```
echo day | sed 's/day/night/' | od -c
```

I got

```
37777776620   n   i   g   h   t   \0   d   a   y   \n
37777776620
```

I hear you on the copy and paste recommendation, but I couldn't seem to do copy or paste in this "terminal emulator" app.

Comment: Did enclose the sed statement in quotes? so echo day | sed 's/day/night/'

Comment: I just tried it with the single quotes, on the command line.  same response:  "nightday" (I had it reversed in my original post but I just fixed it, sorry have a sore throat today and can't think straight...)

Comment: That should have given a syntax error. Does this work: `echo day | sed 's/day/night/'` ?

Comment: I tried it again with the single quotes:
echo day | sed 's/day/night/'
and the response was: 
nightday
This is also the kind of behavior I experienced when trying to put sed commands in a sh script.

Comment: Wait a second. Please [edit] your question and post the output of: `echo day | od -c` and `echo day |  sed 's/day/night/' | od -c`. Copy/paste directly if at all possible.

Comment: Okay, I tried to do as you asked, though I couldn't seem to do copy or paste, and I apologize I don't know how to format my posts on stackexchange using this mobile device.  But I did get ouput which I added to my original post.

Comment: `sed` with this `--version` output is indeed `busybox`. The strange answer was made because some stupid configure scripts require GNU `sed` and test for `GNU sed version`, but the author did not want to lie and add "this is not". But no busybox `sed` ever did what you describe.